# why does this code not return a python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, dataframe

Can anyone explain to me why this code does not create a pandas df?

I expect a df named 'sector_tickers', why does none get created?

```
def scrape_list(site):
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib.request.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    sector_tickers = dict()
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        col = row.findAll('td')
        if len(col) > 0:
            sector = str(col[3].string.strip()).lower().replace(' ', '_')
            ticker = str(col[0].string.strip())
            if sector not in sector_tickers:
                sector_tickers[sector] = list()
            sector_tickers[sector].append(ticker)
    return sector_tickers
```

Thank you for your help. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: You've created an empty dict and then assigned as values lists and then returned this dict why do you expect this to be a df?

Comment: If you changed your last line to `return pd.DataFrame(sector_tickers)` then it will return a df

Comment: Thanks Ed, When I edit to your last line and prints the output:

It is apparent that the output is a pandas panel (3D) and not a dataframe.

How might I change this to become a df?

health_care                  <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: ...
materials                    <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>

Comment: Sorry I have no context as to how your func is being called, if this is being appended to some existing df then you need to show how this is being called. You could try returning a Series object rather than a DataFrame so `return pd.Seriessector_tickers)` but I can't tell if this will work or not without more code and input data and you showing what it currently looks like